# Javascript not chaning html tags

Tags: javascript, java

So I am making a java application that using a website interface. I have a setting button that opens a popup menu where the user can change their name, picture, etc. When they change their name or picture it will save that they have changed it and close the popup menu like I want. But after it closes on the main screen where the user can see their picture and name on the side, it will not update.

This is the button that saves it. Works.

```
<button id="saveSettings" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
```

Now here is the 'saveSettings'. This semi works.

```
        $('#saveSettings').click(function() {
        settings.save();
        loadSettings();
    });
```

Here is the settings.save

```
    save: function() {
    var scanExcludes = settings.getExcludes();
    var scanRestrictions = settings.getRestrictions();
    var scanPaths = settings.getAllScanPaths();
    var searchEngine = settings.getDefaultSearchEngine();
    var displayName = settings.getUsername();
    var avatarPath = settings.getAvatar();
    saveSettings(scanExcludes, scanRestrictions, scanPaths, searchEngine, displayName, avatarPath);
    alertify.success("Settings Saved.");
},
```

Here is loadSettings

```
        browser.registerFunction("loadSettings", args -> {
        final Thread one = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JuicySettings settings = new JuicySettings();
                settings.loadSettings(browser);
            }
        };
        one.start();
        return JSValue.create(true);
    });

    public void loadSettings(final Browser browser) {
    final String data = FileUtil.readFile(settingsPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    final String bytesEncoded = Base64.encode(data.getBytes());

    String script = "settings.load('%s');";
    script = String.format(script, bytesEncoded);
    script = script.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", " ");

    browser.executeJavaScript(script);
}
```

Here is the load function.

```
    load: function(data) {
    var decoded = atob(data);
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(decoded);
    settings.setDisplayName(jsonData.displayName);
    settings.setAvatar(jsonData.avatarPath);
    settings.setScanPaths(jsonData.scanPaths);
    settings.setRestrictions(jsonData.scanRestrictions);
    settings.setExcludes(jsonData.scanExcludes);
    return true;
},
```

When saveSettings is called, 'settings.save();' works fine. But the loadSettings won't updated the display name and avatar.

Here is the setDisplayName and setAvatar functions.

```
    setAvatar: function(path) {
    $('#settingsAvatar').attr('src', path);
    $('#sideBarAvatar').attr('src', path);

},
setDisplayName: function(displayName) {
    $('#inputDisplayName').val(displayName);
    $('.nav-username').html(displayName);
},
```

Been working on this all day and have got no where if anyone would help I would love it.

Comment: What the <expletive> does this have to do with Java?